# Why are valves preferentially affected in endocarditis?

Tags: human-biology, pathology, cardiology, pathophysiology

The inside of the heart is covered by endothelium throughout. Why are valves predisposed to endocarditis? I know it can affect other structires like the septum, chordae etc. But why the valves? Especially bacterial endocarditis.

Wouldn't a place on the ceiling of the atria be quieter and have less turbulence?

Robbin's Pathology says that valves derive nutrition from the surrounding blood and there vessels but mostly on the proximal side. So it might not be due to nutrition.

Are there theories for this?